# Flutter: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. Here: AppBar(

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter, so I wanted to write a simple App and learn how flutter works.

I wanted a App-Bar which should be orange (255, 127, 0, 1), with the menue-Icon in white (size: 100) and the text "Test".
Below the App-Bar I wanted the App to display "Hello World".

But the App doesn't start and this message apears:

> *"Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
>   Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments."*

That's my code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomeSite()));

class HomeSite extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white, size: 100,) ,
        title: Text('Fity'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 127, 0, 1),
      ),
        body: Text('Hello World'),

    );
  }
}
```

The issue is AppBar**(**
Can someone help me? Thank you in advance! ^^

Comment: oh... in the last line I mean, AppBar(. I wanted the "(" to be bold because VS Code underlines this charter red.

Comment: Icon(....) is a positional argument. Specify what named argument you meant there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Icon Widget to some property like leading or trailing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomeSite()));

class HomeSite extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       leading: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white, size: 100,) ,
        title: Text('Fity'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 127, 0, 1),
      ),
      body: Text('Hello World'),

    );
  }
}
```